# Adding two variables to a QComboBox

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qcombobox

Here's my code snippet:

```
self.cursor.execute("MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n.firstname, n.lastname")
for i in self.cursor:
    self.cbPerson.addItem(str(i[0])
```

This gives me a list of the firstnames.

```
self.cbPerson.addItem(str(i[0:3])
```

This gives me the first and last name but like this `('firstname','lastname')`

how do I get the desired output: firstname lastname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use join:

```
for i in self.cursor:
    self.cbPerson.addItem(" ".join(i))
```

or better:

```
self.cbPerson.addItems([" ".join(i) for i in self.cursor])
```